# Python module **slackclient** installs correctly, but will not import ... is it known under another name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api

I am trying to get a module `slackclient` installed in a virtual Python environment.

```
python3 -m venv slackenv
. slackenv/activate
pip3 install slackclient
```

I get

```
python3.7
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan 12 2022, 23:27:58) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import slackclient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'
```

This is with `slackclient` installed both in the virtualenv and in the main system pip list. (It shows up in both lists).

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the name of the package is `slackclient`, the actual module is  `slack`, as can you see [in the official page of the package](https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/). So, try this one:

```py
import slack
```

it should work.